# How to ensure that I've entered the server and how to create a directory there?

Tags: ssh, cluster

I want to run a Fortran code on the server. I am able to log into the server using the command

```
ssh -X username@I.P.address
```

There is no error message. It asks for the password. After I provide the password I get

```
* Documentation: help.ubuntu.com 
487 packages can be updated. 
349 updates are security updates. 
Last login: Mon Nov 20 17:19:01 2017 from IP address
mithu@mithu-Inspiron-3521:~$
```

It doesn't return the name of the server.

Next, I want to create a directory on the server.

I used `mkdir directoryname` command to create a directory.

But when I enter the command `ls` it shows all folders in my home directory on my desktop. (I'm using Ubuntu.) i.e., it creates a directory in my home folder **not** in the server.

In that case, how should I copy my Fortran code in the server and run it from the server?

How do I know that I've entered the server and created a directory there?

Comment: @Archemar Apologize for my ignorance. I'm attempting to connect to the server (the cluster of my institute).

Comment: @roaima No error message. It asks for the password.  After I provide the password I get "* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

487 packages can be updated.
349 updates are security updates.

Last login: Mon Nov 20 17:19:01 2017 from IP address
mithu@mithu-Inspiron-3521:~$"

Comment: @roaima After I login, and enter hostname, it displays username@username -Inspiron-3521 :-( :-( It doesn't return the name of the server. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IP address you have provided to `ssh` is the IP address of your own client machine, not of the cluster you want to reach.

The net result is that you're actually logging on to your own machine.

---

When you want to copy a file to the remote system, remember that remote paths without a leading `/` are relative to your remote system's home directory. So for example, this command will copy a file `localfile` to the `new` subdirectory of your home directory on the remote system as `remotecopy`

```
scp -p localfile remoteuser@remoteip:new/remotecopy
```

You can omit `remotecopy` if the target filename is the same as the source filename. You can omit everything after the colon `:` if you are copying files to your home directory on the remote server.

The `-p` flag is documented in the man page for `scp` (`man scp`) as preserving file modification times and file permissions.

Comment: That was my guess also.  (-:

Comment: @roaima Thanks. This was the problem. :-)

Comment: @roaima But I still face a problem with copying. With the command "scp mithu/home/fortran/program.f :mithu@serverIPaddress: home/mithu/new" I get back "home/mithu/new: No such file or directory". Why is this happening? I have created the directory "new" in the server using "mkdir new" and I have "program.f" in my home folder with the directory name "fortran".

Answer (score 4):

> it creates a directory in my home folder not in the server.

Actually, assuming you entered `mkdir directoryname` on the command line after providing your password to the `ssh -X username@I.P.address` command, you successfully created a directory "in your home folder **on** the server."

> how should I copy my Fortran code in the server and run it from the server?

If you want to copy your Fortran program/source there, you issue this command:

```
scp -r /path/to/Fortran/program username@I.P.address:directoryname/
```

> How do I know that I've entered the server and created a directory there?

You could type `hostname`, it should return the name of the server. You can also type `uname -a` which will give you even more information on the server such as OS etc.

Now, you do not disclose which system (OS) is running on your desktop machine, since you ask these questions, I doubt it is a Linux/unix system, so you might have to look for an scp client for your system. WinSCP is a Windows client that allows you to copy files to your server from Windows.

EDIT:
After op's comment:

```
$ ssh zuse
Password:
Last login: Mon Nov 20 12:57:33 2017 from 192.168.1.73
Have a lot of fun...
jdoe@zuse:~> mkdir stackexchange
jdoe@zuse:~> uname -a
Linux zuse 4.11.3-1-default #1 SMP Thu May 25 17:55:04 UTC 2017 (7262353) aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
jdoe@zuse:~> ls
agent  bin  jbs  myProg.cpp  stackexchange  svn  test  tmp
jdoe@zuse:~>
```

This is what I did to create a directory on my Raspberry pi running Suse 64-bit that I affectionately named `zuse` (Suse has nothing to do with Zuse, it is just a pun of mine ....).

Now, if on your system you see a directory of the same name on your desktop, that means your home folder is a network share, which means that you can access all files in your home folder from the server, cool, hey ? This means that, provided your Fortran code is in your home directory, it is already accessible on the server.

If you want to copy the code to the server, you will have to create a directory on the server, you might need to ask the server administrators for a directory ... Note that this is not really required, since you can already access your Fortran code, provided you store it in your home folder or directories within your home folder ;-).

Comment: The problem is that using the command 'ls' lists all the items in the home folder on my desktop. I'm using Ubuntu. After I login, and enter hostname, it displays username@username -Inspiron-3521 :-( :-( @thecarpy

Comment: @thecapry But I still face a problem with copying. With the command "scp mithu/home/fortran/program.f :mithu@serverIPaddress: home/mithu/new" I get back "home/mithu/new: No such file or directory". Why is this happening? I have created the directory "new" in the server using "mkdir new" and I have "program.f" in my home folder with the directory name "fortran". Why is this error message flashing?

Comment: There is a space here: `serverIPaddress: home/mithu/new` .... it should be `serverIPaddress:new` OR `serverIPaddress:/home/mithu/new` ! If you connect as `mithu` the two are equivalent ... if you see `new` in your home folder, copy `program.f` to `new` in your home folder and connect to your server, it should be in the `new` folder there as well ;-) Your `home` folder is on another server, shared with all servers you connect to ;-)